# Post-fix calculator in C++ -> How to manipulate elements from stack (dynamic array)

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, calculator, postfix-notation

_
hey there - first time asking a question here since I'm stuck:

I've been asked to create a post-fix (stack) calculator in C++, I intent for it to store integers in the stack until an operator is given (+,-,*,/) after which it will pop the last 2 integers with the operator given.
I know that there exists a stack function in C++ with #include < stack > , but I was given the following code to build on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T> class node
{
public:
    node();
    node(T);

    T value;
    node<T>*next;
};

template<class T>node<T>::node()
{
    value=0;
    next=0;
}
template<class T>node<T>::node(T t)
{
    value=t;
    next=0;
}
```

and the Stack class header based on node.h

```
#include"node.h"

template <class T>class stack
{
public:
    stack();
    void push(T);
    T pop();

protected:
    int count;
    node<T>*head;
};

template<class T>stack<T>::stack()
{
    count=0;
    head=0;
}

template<class T> void stack<T>::push(T x)
{
    node<T> *u = new node<T>(x);

    u->next = head;
    head = u;
    count++;
}

template<class T> T stack<T>::pop()
{
    T x;
    node<T> *u;
    if (count == 0)
        return x;
    x = head->value;
    u = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete u;
    count--;        
    return x;
}
```

Now in theory, I create a stack of integers called stacky with `stack<int> stacky;`
then I will be getting integer input via `std::cin >> x;` where x is an int inside an infinite loop and I will be pushing them down the stack via `stacky.push(x);` until I receive an operator, where I will use the top integer  second to top integer, then pop those two elements and then push the result down the stack.

In order for this to be done, I have to be able to get the top element of the array and the second to top, but everything I tried so far resulted in an error.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What did you try? What was the error?

Comment: Hello Barry I tried making a node<int> nodee;
and trying to get nodee(head) etc since I assume that nodes take the place of dynamic arrays in stack but it is giving me an ündeclared identifier

Comment: You have a `stack<int>`. That should take care of all of the internals for the stack. You should focus on what methods of `stack<int>` you want to use for which parts of this problem.

Comment: Well, I will be getting an input which I will find out if it's an integer number, operator or invalid input - If it's an int, I will just push it down the stack with stacky.push(input) - this is how the push method will be used. If it's an operator, it will take the top element of the stack and the second to top element and do the operation on them (if the 2 top elements are 3 and 5 and it receives a + it will pop them using the pop method, then push 8 on the stack using the push method). What I can't do is manipulate the elements of the dynamic array to make it happen

Comment: Sounds like you know how to solve the problem. I don't know why you think you need to "manipulate the elements of the dynamic array" - or what that means (there are no arrays here, dynamic or otherwise). Just stick with `push` and `pop` and you'll be fine.

Comment: How can I create a calculator with just the push and pop? The push pushes an integer down the stack, the pop deletes the two top integers (pops them). I still need a way to do an operation with those two top integers and I can't figure of a way to do it without accessing the elements

Comment: No, `pop` removes and returns the top value. Just call it twice to get the top two values. A stack is a well-defined data structure, you can look up it's behaviour if reading the implementation gets confusing. (Even better, just use `std::stack` and read its documentation - it is better designed than this implementation anyway).

Comment: Update your question with code you have tried (post actual code, not a free prose description) and the errors you have received (actual errors copied and pasted from the output of your compiler).

Comment: Useless, thanks a lot! You are definitely not useless :) I just figured it out.  Still, though - what if I'd like to print the stack or the last two integers every time an input is given, is there absolutely no way to reference elements uniquely?